# Remote Windows Host Disconnected From Everything When Logging Out From RDP

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop

I have a remote Windows host running Hyper-V virtual machines and I am using the popular service "Tailscale" to act like a VPN to reach the remote network. Due to compliance, I have to sleep the computer each night (the computer must not be visibly on). What I do is I wrote a Wake-On-LAN bash script in the router of that network and I will manually run it each morning to wake the computer. This has been going fine for context but below is where I will describe the problem.

I will RDP into the main computer OS to do some administrative tasks such as checking Hyper-V settings, etc. then I disconnect from the RDP session. I continue to `ssh` into a guest VM hosted by that PC but not a minute goes by and my `ssh` session gets disconnected. When I try to RDP into the computer, it also does not work. The only way I can fix this is by going back into the router and running that Wake-On-LAN script and everything works again. This is super annoying because I cannot reasonably get any work done on the `ssh` session before spending time reconfiguring everything just for it to break.

I did research about RDP locking sessions and timing out but I did all the modifications in Group Policy Editor but that still does not work and my VMs are all getting disconnected.

EDIT: I should also mention that my power plan is set to never sleep, never turn off display, link state power management is off, selective USB suspending is off.

Comment: Have you checked whether the server is going to sleep? It would show in the event log for example. Mentioned because a wake-on-lan packet does *nothing* to running machines (unless your script does more stuff after). Do you do anything else when connecting to your router to run the script, like disconnect your vpn? Does Tailscale show the server is still connected+can you ping it?

Comment: Tailscale shows the server as disconnected so I suspect the machine is going to sleep. However, nothing shows up in event log.

Comment: Try running `powercfg /sleepstudy` on the host and check the resulting report? Depending on your config, the tailscale routes might be getting overwritten by hyper-v, effectively disconnecting it for example, but it would be hard to tell without running something every minute on the host like `DATE /T >> %temp%\routes.log && route print >> %temp%\routes.log`. Are you able to run the client on your guest VM(s) instead of the host itself?

Comment: I did run the client on the Guest VM, its that the host apparently goes to standby mode when I run `powercfg /sleepstudy` and I do not know why.

Comment: What's the exact wording of the report (or is it unable to generate the report)? If the report says it's going into standby, then there will be event logs that say why. Open event viewer, and filter to "Event logs=System" and "Event sources=Kernel-Power,Power-Troubleshooting" (select both) and see if there's anything weird. Installing hyper-v is supposed to disable some standby modes, so check `powercfg /availablesleepstates` and see which states are enabled for the host

Comment: Event viewer says this about the system: "The system is entering sleep. Reason: System Idle"

Comment: Is that what it says every time you get disconnected? Double check the sleep settings on the host, and run `powercfg /list` to make sure the active* power plan is the one you actually made changes to. If your host is in a windows domain, there may be policies applying different sleep timer settings than you expect

Answer (score 0):

From Tailscale's [Troubleshooting guide](https://tailscale.com/kb/1023/troubleshooting):

> **Unable to make a TCP connection between two nodes**
>
> If your nodes are
> visible in the admin console, and there is no access rule blocking
> connections between the nodes, check the level of connectivity with
> Tailscale’s three types of ping:
>
> - `ping 100.x.x.x` tells the OS to send an ICMP ping across the tailnet
> - `tailscale ping 100.x.x.x` tests whether the two tailscaled processes
>   can communicate at all, and how (direct, or relayed)
> - `tailscale ping --tsmp 100.x.x.x` sends a packet that goes one level further than `tailscale ping`, also going through the WireGuard level, but doesn’t
>   involve the host’s networking stack Packet size limits can also cause
>   connection problems on certain types of networks.
>
> Tailscale uses a MTU of 1280. If there are other interfaces which
> might send a packets larger than this, those packets might get dropped
> silently. These can be verified by using tcpdump.
>
> In order to solve this, we can set the MTU at the LAN level to a lower
> value, or use MSS (Maxiumum Segment Size) clamping.

Note that Hyper-V VM interfaces might each have their own MTU depending on the networking settings